# rails auto_html gem is not persisting results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to rails development and I am trying to get the auto_html gem to work, but nothing ever gets saved to the body_html field of the DB. I am not getting any errors either, so it seems like the gem just isn't getting called.

I have included the gem in my gemfile and ran bundle install. Am I not doing something correctly? My thought was that I didn't need to call any auto_html method anywhere because I have the auto_html_for in the model.

I am on Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3p125 and auto_html 1.5.1

Model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign

  auto_html_for :body do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @video = Video.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @video }
    end
  end

  def create
    @video = Video.new(params[:video])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to videos_path(:campaign => "#{@video.campaign_id}"), notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @video, status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for @video do |f|

  .field
    = f.hidden_field :campaign_id, :value => "#{params[:campaign]}"

    = f.text_area :body
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

**EDIT:** videos table definition from schema.rb

```
create_table "videos", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.text     "body_html"
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
```

Comment: What version of auto_html gem are you using? You don't need include AutoHtml in controller btw. Try to experiment in console a bit. For example what's the output in console when you do this: Video.new(:body => 'test') – Dejan Simic 31 secs ago edit

Comment: 1.9.3p125 :001 > Video.new(:body => "test")
 => #<Video id: nil, body: "test", body_html: nil, campaign_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: 1.9.3p125 :002 > Video.create(:body => "test")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `videos` (`body`, `body_html`, `campaign_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test', NULL, NULL, '2012-03-29 17:10:36', '2012-03-29 17:10:36')
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Video id: 11, body: "test", body_html: nil, campaign_id: nil, created_at: "2012-03-29 17:10:36", updated_at: "2012-03-29 17:10:36">

Comment: Also, I am on auto_html version 1.5.1

Comment: Hi, same problem here. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @lakim no I haven't and I haven't had time to investigate further as I am busy working on other features of the site. If you find a solution please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

auto_html_for didn't worked well with Rails 3.2.1+

Install the latest auto_html version (1.5.2).